# Project can't finding translation resource

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 project that has a farm model that I need translations for. I am in the metadata class that I have created and know works.

My problem is that when I go to set the file lookup reference with the

```html
 [Display(Name = "Farm Name", ResourceType = typeof(Translations))]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required",
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Translations))] 
public string name { get; set; }
```

The typeOf(Translations))] throwing an error saying

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Translations' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the using statement that points to the App_globalResources folder also.